# Form not POSTing but GET works just fine

Tags: php

First of all, I am familiar with programming but new to PHP.

This problem happened since I started PHP on this computer.
The things I've done to get to this are

1. Clean windows install
2. Install only XAMPP and PHPStorm
3. Followed the exact instructions in the JetBrains setup guide
4. Tried the most minimalistic approach and still get nowhere

Here's the form in HomePage.html

```
<form action="FormHandler.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nameInput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="subButton"/>
</form>
```

and here's the FormHandler.php code

```
<?php
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

If I type localhost into chrome I get greeted with the XAMPP Dashboard 
If I do phpinfo(), I get the list with my PHPinfo so PHP works 
If I change my form to `method="get"` the request works!

Comment: It is quite simple code, did you check with $_POSt variable,

Comment: I did, var_dump($_POST) gives me an empty array and var_dump($_GET) gives me an array with 2 object as it should.

Comment: try with this,  $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input"); while using post. it must print all data

Comment: @developerCK That does actually work with POST, but not with GET

Answer (score 1):

Check your httpd.conf and .htaccess to see if POST requests are being filtered.

It could be that these are filtered out of security reasons.

Also, you may want to check in php.ini if for any reason, the `request_order` ini directive has been altered so that the $_REQUEST does not contain the POST variables.

Comment: request_order in the php.ini file shows Default Value: None and the other 2 on "GP". I've opened the httpd.conf file but I don't see any filters anywhere, I also wouldn't understand why it would filter if I did a normal fresh install without tampering with any settings

Comment: @JimVekemans I'm also not sure on why. Maybe you're working out of the XAMPP control site directory, which is more secured or something. Did you also check the .htaccess in the working directory and its parent directories? You might want to look at something like `<Limit GET> ` or `<LimitExcept POST>`

Comment: No Limits set in .htaccess either. What's I'm having the same issue on my laptop using WAMP instead of XAMPP

Comment: Are you sure you pasted *all* your code? Also please have a look in the PHP and Apache error logs and see if you see anything of importance in there